# Sending json with $.post in express/node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, express

This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var $ = require('jquery');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./views/index.html', {"root": __dirname});
});


app.post('/contact/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);

});
```

and my post request from another file, which is called when a form is submitted:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $('#message').val();
    var email = $('#EmailInput').val();
    var reason = $('#reason').val();

    $.post('/contact', { 'content': content, 'email': email, 'reason': reason }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

However, whenever the form is submitted, the post request is successful, it's just no data has been passed.

req and req.body both return undefined. I can't figure out why.

Comment: you have ```console.log(res.body);``` in your code, it should be ```req.body```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to log the response in app.js -- you should log the request, instead!

Comment: Whoops. Even when I change that though, still undefined. Any other theories?

Comment: "[*By default, it is `undefined`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body), and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).*"

Comment: Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @Maggs They each cover different formats, so you'll want to choose based on which the route expects. For simple form data (no files), the [format jQuery uses](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) by default with Ajax `data`, [`body-parser`'s `urlencoded()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparser-urlencoded-options) should be appropriate. If you need to support files with `multipart`, then use `multer`.

Answer (score 0):

you need the body parser to populate the body property of the request object

```
npm install body-parser
```

then include

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

documentation for your particular use case and tweaking may be found [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

edit: be sure to include this BEFORE your route handlers are declared